# Python - decorator calling inner function?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm currently trying out decorators and I can't understand one thing. I have simple decorator:

```
def new_decorator(func):
    print "Calling new_decorator()"
    def wrap(arg):
        print "Calling wrap()"
        func(arg)
    return wrap  

@new_decorator
def foo(name):
    print name
```

Upon running we get:

```
'Calling decorate()'
```

Only after calling `foo`:

```
>>> foo('Jon')
Calling wrap()
Jon
```

Till now I understand everything (I think). `new_decorator(func)` is called at the start, with `foo` as parameter and it returns `wrap`. But now I tried decorators with parameters:

```
def add_attr(varname, value):
    def decorate(func):
        print "Calling decorate()"
        setattr(func, varname, value)
        return func
    return decorate

@add_attr('var', 'New attribute')
def foo():
    print "Calling foo()"
    print foo.var
```

When running it (without calling `foo()`) it returns:

```
'Calling decorate()'
```

After `foo()`:

```
>>> foo()
Calling foo()
New attribute
```

What I can't understand is, **why this "inner" function `decorate` is called** at the start, before even calling `foo`? In first example it wasn't. And how was function `foo` send as a parameter to `decorate`? `add_attr` gets only 2 parameters, and neither of them is `foo`.

Comment: Perhaps because you *call*? If you added rounded brackets around something you call that item...

Comment: The second case is similar to `add_attr('var', 'New attribute')(foo)` which already calls the inner decorate.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I get it, thanks!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What I meant was "Why inner `decorate` was called even before calling `foo`?" Now I understand, thanks to @Moses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally need 3 layers of nesting for a decorator which accepts arguments.  Think of a decorator which accepts arguments as a "decorator maker".  **It should return a decorator when called**.

To understand this, consider that the code below

```
@new_decorator
def foo(name):
    print name
```

Is really just syntax sugar for this:

```
def foo(name):
    print name

foo = new_decorator(foo)
```

So, similarly, this:

```
@add_attr('var', 'New attribute')
def foo():
    print "Calling foo()"
    print foo.var
```

Is identical to this:

```
def foo():
    print "Calling foo()"
    print foo.var

foo = add_attr('var', 'New attribute')(foo)
```

That should guide you in the correct direction for writing `add_attr` correctly.

If you're still confused after making a few attempts, I refer you to [a famous answer from e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/674039) that explains decorators better than anything else I've seen on the web.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it!